# REQUEST_URL if statements

Tags: php

I'm a PHP rookie, I have the following statement:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>Hello World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/blog')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>blog World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';    
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/videos')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>videos World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';  
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/about')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>about World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/contact')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>contact World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>'; 
}
```

My issue is that whenever I go elsewhere than `http://website.com/` I still get the result `Hello World` rather than the other results. Any Idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: Because other url patterns has `/` also

Comment: but doesn't an `else if` check over run an `if` check?

Comment: For example, when you go ..../videos it will match first check. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/blog`, `/videos`, ... also has `/`. So which url you go, it will always match with `/`. You can use this;

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') {
    echo '<span>Hello World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/blog')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>blog World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';    
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/videos')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>videos World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';  
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/about')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>about World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/contact')!=-1) {
    echo '<span>contact World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>'; 
}
```

Comment: @user3352340 upvote and confirm would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` doesn't return -1, it returns `false` if there is no match. Therefore your tests should be:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') !== false)
```

etc.

(!== and === are stricter comparison operators and means that PHP won't equate 0 to false in the comparison)

You should also realise that the first comparison, against '/' will match all instances, as all strings will start with '/'. Therefore you should have it as the last condition, not the first.

Overall it would be clearer if you used more positive comparisons:

```
if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/blog') === 0 ) {
    echo '<span>blog World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';    
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/videos') === 0) {
    echo '<span>videos World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';  
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/about') === 0) {
    echo '<span>about World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/contact') === 0 ) {
    echo '<span>contact World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>'; 
}else if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') === 0) {
    echo '<span>Hello World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI' === '/') {
    echo '<span>Hello World' .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. '</span>';   
} else {
    echo '<span>URL Not matched</span>';   
}
```

If the string matches that URI at the beginning (which it should) then the index returned will be exactly 0, so the exact match will match all occurances. I've changed your last match to match exactly '/' as if there is no match for that you would likely want to return an error, but you could just have a default action in the final else.